# Is there a way to switch the mesh selection mode by a shortcut?

Tags: mesh, shortcut, selection-tools

Is there a shortcut for switching between these three modes?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This can be accomplished by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. This will bring up the shown popup, in which you can select either Vertex, Edge, or Face mode. Note that you can use <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, and <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, and <kbd>3</kbd> to complete the action using shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. Using a V, E or F buttons after inputting the Ctrl+Tab shortcut is a great solution I haven't heard about before.

Comment: You can also use 1, 2 or 3 to select vert, edge or face respectively (based on the order they appear in the list).

Comment: You can by the way also add your own hotkeys in the right click menu of the items here. So no need to create the hotkey nodes by hand. Right click at Vertex, add shortcut ...

Comment: Oh Man, @Tilles, your comment is deserve to be converted to an answer here so we can endorse it. Kudos man, it is what I looked for for years!

Comment: For Blender 2.8 see [angabriel's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/130078/68286)

Answer (score 12):

It's 2019 ;)

Blender 2.80 became much more intuitive. The hotkeys for the select mode are now pre-configured.

Number keys **1, 2, 3** switch between **vertex, edge, face** selection mode.

Another important thing: If you have configured to emulate a numpad, you have to change the shortcuts from `1` to `Numpad-1`.

Search for `mesh.select_mode` in Preferences->Keymap

Comment: I actualy made these as custom shortcuts some time ago

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the Ctrl-Tab no longer works

Answer (score 7):

If you prefer to have own shortcuts, you can create custom ones in the *Input* section of *Blenders User Preferences* *(File > User-Preferences > Input)*. Open the *3D View* section, and add your shortcut to the *Mesh* section:

[image: addon prefs]

You'll need to fill in the path of the operator to call. For the Mesh selection, this will be `view3d.select_component`. Once done, define the keystroke you like, and choose a type from the dropdown box which appeared after setting the operator. Note: Even if the dropdown box already says 'Vertex', choose the option again. The box will be greyed out until you do that, and the keystroke won't function. Save *User Settings* after that, and enjoy your own keymap!

[image: shortcut]

Answer (score 5):

After pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, you can use <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>3</kbd> in place of <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>F</kbd> *I find it flow better to end the gesture :)*

In every menu/popup you can use these key shortcuts, notice underlined letters.

Answer (score 2):

It's 2018 so let me add the shortcut command name for Blender 2.79:

[image: shortcut command]

`mesh.select_mode` is what you need for toggling vertex/edge/face in edit mode.

You want to add it under `User Preference -> Input -> 3D View -> Mesh` as described by [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/59032)

Answer (score 0):

I was asking the same questions when tried to learn Blender editor. I know that such a feature exists in the Lightwave 3D editor, but for some reason develepers of Blender forgot about it. Hopefully, Blender allows to add missing features with add-ons.

For the third version of Blender 3D editor you can use this add-on:
https://github.com/neverwinter-nights/Mesh-Selection-Mode-Cycle

It adds two actions:

- one to switch to a next mode,
- one to switch to a previous mode.

Key combinations can be assigned to these actions to your liking.