# How to assign a keyboard shortcut for a mesh selection mode?

Tags: interface

I want a keyboard shortcut for switching between selecting things; vertices, faces and points. One key for each, not a pop up menu where i have to select with the mouse. Does this exist? Modelling should be like playing a piano or something, a key for everything, minimal aiming the mouse pointer att small icons, this aiming the mouse att small icons all the time is so.. breaks the flow.. Im sure it exists but i cant find it anywhere?

Comment: Blender provides Shortcut Keys. http://download.blender.org/documentation/BlenderHotkeyReference.pdf

Comment: See related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21383/is-there-a-way-to-switch-the-mesh-selection-mode-by-a-shortcut

Comment: I vote to reopen this question since OP wanted to have 'One key for each [mesh selection mode], not a pop up menu where i have to select with the mouse'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In *Edit Mode* press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to open a *Mesh Select Mode* pop up menu. Hover the mouse cursor over a selection type you want to add a shortcut to, press **RMB**-->***Add Shortcut*** and input a desired keyboard button.
[image]

You may *change or remove a shortcut* in the same way.
[image]

Comment: Thats IT!!! Perfect solution, thanks super much Gonzou!!

Comment: Great to hear that mooz :). If my post helped you to solve your problem, please mark it as accepted using the check mark at the top left of the post. Also could you rename your question to something like ''How to assign a keyboard shortcut for a mesh selection mode?'' so other people may find it easier. Thanks.

Comment: Changing between these is so common that I'm amazed people don't go crazy over the extra keystrokes. Especially since ctrl-tab requires quite a bit of hand movement to reach both keys, and then reposition again to choose VEF or use the mouse to do so. This same question has been asked many times since the first one I saw from 2006 (in blender forum I think) with the same answer of "You can press ctrl-tab."  Thank you so much for this tip on adding hotkeys from menus!