# Short-cut for "cursor to selected"

Tags: customization, shortcut, 3d-cursor

Can I program a direct short-cut (keyboard) for the functions "cursor to selected" and "selection to cursor"? Couldn't find them under the User Preference/Input tab. I know they're under <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, but then I still have to select from the pull-down menu, and that is too cumbersome.

Comment: Perhaps you already know this, but for pulldowns it often helps to use the menu accelerators. You can use the number row to select entries in order (`1` for the top entry, `2` for the second, `3` for the third, etc.). Or you can use the letter key corresponding to the underlined letter in the entry you want. For example both `Shift S` `2` and `Shift S` `T` will snap the selection to the cursor.

Comment: @gandalf3♦ I answered similar question some time ago and presented the same solution (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/how-to-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-mesh-selection-mode). The answer got 'duplicate' status and was closed, but I think it shouldn't be (cause it shows different solution from the one that NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ aka HATMAN presented). Could you please reopen it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Bring up your snap menu with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Hover your mouse over '*cursor to selected*', and then click on it with the <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd>. You will see an option to either add or change the keyboard shortcut.

Hover your mouse over the box that appears, (it should tell you to press a key), and then press the desired shortcut one key at a time while still holding them down to create your new shortcut.

Make sure to save your new shortcut as defaults by going to *user preferences* by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>,  and then *save user settings*.

[image: animated gif showing the process of creating a shortcut]

---

In 2.8 and later, you can add a new shortcut to [*Quick Favorites*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/tool_system.html?#quick-favorites) which will give you a small menu with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Q</kbd>

Simply <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> and select *Add to Quick Favorites* from the choices that appear.

[image]

Comment: Gifs may make your answers clearer. Read here how to create them: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers

Answer (score 9):

Make a user-defined keyboard shortcut.

I sacrifice the default shortcut for *To Sphere* (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and made it `bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()` instead.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to sacrifice, there is "Add new..." button visible