# Is there an Addon that positions 3D cursor at the origin of non selected object by clicking it in 3D View?

Tags: 3d-view, add-on, snapping, 3d-cursor

I've been watching tutorials and trying Addons, that led me to install Sensei Format addon, I didn't like how it changes many of the shortcuts that I got used to, yet one feature grabbed my attention, when clicking to set the 3D cursor in 3D view, if I click on an object, the 3D cursor location will snap to the object's origin. While reviewing Sensei Format, I found out that it's basically a personalization of features that already exist in Blender and in other Addons, for instance I managed to call the create object menu in 3D view by double right click instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>. Is there an Addon, or a way, to activate the 3D cursor snap to object origin in 3D view?

Comment: See this question-http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43133/short-cut-for-cursor-to-selected/43135#43135

Comment: I'm not sure it's related, the question in link is discussing adding shortcuts, this is not my quetion @Timaroberts

Comment: I'm not aware of an add on that will do this for you but you can set your own shortcuts for most things. That's why I added the link.

Comment: Thinking about it, since there is no (Cursor to Origin of non selected object) in Blender ;P it must be a script with multiple functions: First it selects the left clicked object. Second, it (Snap > Cursor to Selected). Third, it undo the selection process, reverting it to the previous status, meaning re-selecting whatever was selected before this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an addon to do that, you can achieve it with Blender's builtin key map editor.

If the default <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected* is not enough for you, then you can set up any desired key combination to call that operator for you in the key map editor. The operator you are looking for is `view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected`.

With this you can go to Blender user preferences with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> > Input Tab > 3D view > 3D View global and add a new entry there with the *Add new* button at the bottom of the list

In the operator field to the left enter the `view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected` now assign any mouse action or key press as desired.

Depending on which mouse button you use for selecting I found out that using the same mouse button plus some modifier key can work very well.

For example I use Left Mouse button for selection, since in object mode the <kbd>F</kbd> is not bound to any action by default, I assigned <kbd>Mouse Select</kbd> > <kbd>Press</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> as modifier key to `view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected` so when I am selection objects all I have to do is press F key and click on an object and the cursor will snap to all selected.

**Edit** Check out the example image

[image]

Comment: Thank you @DuarteFarrajotaRamos for your answer, please refer to the comments above for more explanation about the question.

Comment: The technique I explained above doesn't snap the cursor to the objects surface, it snaps it to the objects origin or center, that is what the Snap Cursor to Selected operator does. I edited my answer, check the added image.

Comment: I agree, this is the closest result to my question, it ends up with selecting the object, but at least it saves lots of shortcuts, thank you.

Comment: I use right mouse button to select, I assigned double left click to (Cursor to Selected)  this will even make the workflow faster, I select the object with rmb, the double lmb anywhere moves the Cursor to the object's origin! Still what I've seen in that addon is unprecedented, I am more convinced now that there's a custom script lying behind it.

Comment: Well if you really want it only in just one move you can do it by assign the Right Mouse > Press for Select and Right Mouse > Release for Cursor to Selected,  that way you only need one button press, although it may be a pain if you ever want to just select an object without moving the cursor. I didn't suggest this initially because I don't know what nasty side effects it may cause. You can then assign some other hotkey for selecting without moving the mouse cursor, just for safekeeing.

Comment: Yes this will be more painful than useful, the original question is.. Hmmm, I'll try to explain it as far as I can, the way I saw it, he just made the cursor button snap to the origin without even selecting it! I don't want to promote other websites here. But that's how it worked.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, it behaves like a "magnet" thing, you just use regular free positioning of the 3D cursor but it automatically moves to the nearest object origin to where you click it, is that it? Hum in that case there may be some sort of more elaborate python scripting behind it then, I don' know but it sure sounds useful.

Comment: It sure does, to be honest I didn't like how he changed many shortcuts, it didn't work for me at least, so I uninstalled it, but this cursor thing is awesome!

Comment: Just one more thing, You could also look into this addon http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?229754-A-script-to-place-cursor-on-objects-surface-%28and-some-other-functionality%29 although it does have some improved functionality I don't think it provides that exact feature you want, only surface snapping

Comment: Looks interesting!

Answer (score 1):

In object-mode you could go to *Object* > *Snap*, right click on *Cursor to Selected* and choose *Add Shortcut* to turn this into an immediate action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Harag, yet it doesn't answer my question, since (Cursor to Selected) or (Cursor to active) will do exactly what they say. The function I've seen in action,  is left mouse clicking on any object in the 3D view, will snap the Cursor to it's origin, instead of positioning it on it's surface, which Blender does normally, the object is NOT selected, the main difference between Blender default and this function, is positioning the Cursor on the origin instead of the surface, there is no (Cursor to origin) in Blender, so there's no way to assign a shortcut.