# UV editor vert, edge and face selection modes as keybinds?

Tags: customization, shortcut, uv-image-editor

How can I take that bpy.data.scenes python line and make a keybind of it?

[image]

Comment: Can copy from the top console but how does one pass it as the keybind?

Comment: I would have marked this a duplicate of [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/how-to-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-mesh-selection-mode), but it may have been non-obvious that Ctrl+Tab also works in the *UV/Image-Editor*.

Comment: Buttons get asigned using the method you've provided, but nothing happens when I press them. What is causing this ?

Comment: What keyboard keys did you assign them to? It's possible the keys you chose are already in use. I suggest combining Shift, Alt or Ctrl with them to make the shortcut unique. In my example I assigned Shift+Q to *Vertex* mode.

Comment: I just tested 1, 2, 3, and 4 for the selection modes and they worked, so it should work for you.

Comment: Had double asignment on the same button in the same submenu. It is now working as intended. Thank you very much Ray !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a shortcut for the UV selection type *menu*, it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> you can right-click on *Vertex*, *Edge*, *Face* or *Island* and choose *Add Shortcut*.

This is much easier than trying to do it via the key-bindings editor as you can see from the complexity of the new shortcut after it is added:

[image]

To make these new shortcuts appear in all files go to *File*> *User Preferences*> *Save User Settings*.