# Mark seam's shortcut code?

Tags: shortcut

Blender has a lovely system for creating new shortcuts. Can anyone advise me on the code for the "Mark seams" operation? Bonus points for the button-toggle (one button to mark/unmark).

Comment: Two buttons, but you have that on the toolshelf, 'shading/UV' tab. For the shortcut Ctrl+E then choose in the list

Comment: You may also assign your own buttons to these operations in the same manner as here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/how-to-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-mesh-selection-mode

Comment: Paul Gonet deserves a plus because he actually showed hot to create the shortcut (even by just pointing to the solution). U wana post an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and choose "Mark Seam" or "Clear Seam" from the list.
Then, in order to add a shortcut, you can do as explained here: [How to assign a keyboard shortcut for a mesh selection mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/how-to-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-mesh-selection-mode)

Comment: Please aprove my edit to your answer.

Comment: Btw, for anyone concerned, there indeed seems to be no way for a one-button solution. You would need separate buttons for mark and clear.

Comment: You can also (now?) press ctrl + e then press `m` on your keyboard

Answer (score 3):

If you are ready to invest a bit more work (Like I did for my Spacemouse Pro), you can also create a Pie Menu with mark and unmark, so you just need to press a key and move the mouse.

https://vimeo.com/103321600

Code you will need is:

```
pie.operator("mesh.mark_seam", text="Mark Seam", icon='EDGESEL')

pie.operator("mesh.mark_sharp", text="Clear Seam", icon='MESH_CUBE').clear=True
```

Instead of the sample code with pie.operator_enum...

To register it as an add-on to keep it permanent just use the code below on top of your script

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Mark Seam Pie Manu",
    "description": "Edit mode Edge Menu",
    "author": "...",
    "version": (0, 1, 1),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "location": "3D View",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Pie Menu"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the question you want to add shortcut for mark seam

In Edit Mode -> Select the Edge and Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

[image]

and how over the mouse and press right click and select Change shortcut

[image]

As soon as u click on change shortcut u get a pop-up press a key

[image]

I have selected the dot button from left of the keyboard

Now open user preferences and click the save user settings so that next time when you open blender mark seam setting will not disappear.

[image]

Comment: If you copy the entrance at the userpreferences in input/3DView/Mesh you can add even more than one shortcut for the same action (as i recently learned here). This solution is the most simple one you could get!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers. what i do is use CTRL + E then *mark seam* on one edge then for the rest i use SHIFT + R which repeats the last actions. So if you do anything other than selecting the edges like say add another edge loop you need to mark one seam again and then use shift + R to repeat. hope this helps someone, i know this is an old question.