# Hotkey to change select mode?

Tags: selection-tools

I toggle between Vertex, Edge, and Face Select mode constantly. In a speed modeling session, this adds a lot of clicks.

I couldn't find any place to set a hotkey to change this setting. Is there one?

Comment: Please see also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21383/is-there-a-way-to-switch-the-mesh-selection-mode-by-a-shortcut

Comment: Apologies, my poor searches missed those answers. I'll mark this one accepted, but many thanks for the additional links. The info on adding custom hotkeys is invaluable as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>  .

When the menu appears choose the appropriate letter:

<kbd>V</kbd> Vertex select

<kbd>E</kbd> Edge select

<kbd>F</kbd> Face select

Alternatively you can use numbers: <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, and <kbd>3</kbd>

The tooltip shows the Python in case you decide to assign a single keystroke.

Comment: For Blender 2.8 see [angabriel's answer on the non-duplicate question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/130078/68286)